# Send email confirmation for order when using Paypal checkout for Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce, mailchimp

I have setup my eshop on *Woocommerce* and I am sending the invoices using *Mailchimp* automation and integration with *Woocommerce*.

Everything works fine with Cash on Delivery method. When a user makes an order they receive an Order Confirmation e-mail from *Mailchimp*.

The issue is when a user chooses *Paypal* checkout. Then they get all notifications from *Paypal* not from my website and this makes them ask all the time if I received their order and so.

Is there a way for users to get a *Mailchimp* confirmation when they check out with *Paypal*?

Answer (score 1):

PayPal does integrate with MailChimp, you need to setup their PayPal integration. But it only works with 1 MailChimp list, so check that first. If you have multiple lists then they suggest using Zapier.  Also, you need to have a PayPal Business or Premier account.

If you have all that, the MailChimp instructions are [here](https://kb.mailchimp.com/integrations/e-commerce/use-paypal-with-mailchimp), along with all the links to get you setup.

Answer (score 1):

So I managed to solve this:

- Log into your PayPal Business Account
- Profile Settings then My Selling Tools
- Website Payment Preferences -> Update

Here you need to edit the Return URL:
you need to add the order received URL of your Website e.g.:

[www.example.com/checkout/order-received](http://www.example.com/checkout/order-received)

This way PayPal redirects to your website and after that the website sends a signal to MailChimp that the Order was completed. Then MailChimp sends the automated order confirmation e-mail.